# AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'guild'

Tags: python

I am creating a discord bot ticket system. However, when I run the code, I get this error.
I do not know what I have done wrong, Can some of you tell me what I did wrong?
.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sachi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "c:\Users\sachi\Downloads\CDN Ticketing\Main.py", line 11, in ticket
    guild = self.client.get_guild(interaction.guild.id) if interaction.guild else None
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

Here's the full code!

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands, utils 

class TicketLauncher(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, client) -> None:
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.client = client

    @discord.ui.button(label="Open a Ticket", style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, custom_id="Open_Ticket")   
    async def ticket(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        guild = self.client.get_guild(interaction.guild.id) if interaction.guild else None
        user = interaction.user

        if guild and user:
            ticket_channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name=f"ticket-for-{user.name}")

            if ticket_channel is not None: 
                await interaction.response.send_message(f"You have already opened a ticket at {ticket_channel.mention}!", ephemeral=True)
            else:
                overwrites = {
                    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False),
                    user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True, send_message=True, attach_files=True, embed_links=True),
                    guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True, send_message=True, read_message_history=True)
                }
                new_channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name=f"ticket-for-{user.name}", overwrites=overwrites, reason=f"Ticket for {user}")
                await new_channel.send(f"{user.mention} created a ticket!")
                await interaction.response.send_message(f"I've opened a ticket for you at {new_channel.mention}!", ephemeral=True)

class AClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(intents=discord.Intents.default())
        self.synced = False
        self.added = False

    async def on_ready(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()
        if not self.synced:
            await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=1186348400745132043))
            self.synced = True
        print(f"We have logged in as {self.user}.")

        if not self.added:
            self.add_view(TicketLauncher(self))
            self.added = True

client = AClient()
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

@tree.command(guild=discord.Object(id=1186348400745132043), name='ticket', description='Launches the ticket system.')
async def ticketing(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="If you need support, click the button below and open a ticket!",
        color=discord.Colour.red()
    )
    await interaction.channel.send(embed=embed, view=TicketLauncher(client))
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Ticketing system launched", ephemeral=True) 

client.run('MTE4NjM0ODE4ODAzOTM5MzI4MA.Gm_lQW.8R6CmSy8HZmaJmmU2t_q7ktjSGthaLXr_5qaFU')
```

I was trying to create a discord ticket system. However, I get this error, please help me.